# jQuery slide show scrolls page to top when changing image

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have just added a jQuery slide show to our companies website and it all works fine apart from every time the image changes the page jumps to the top and for the life of me I can't figure out why!

The site in question is www.fireguardservices.com

I am a bit new to this so be gentle please and thanks in advance for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the code behind the page you've got a full HTML document embedded inside you original HTML document, which is a big no-no, and would probably cause this sort of problem. The second HTML document begins at line 126.

You need to move the HTML and javascript code out of this second HTML document, place it in the main HTML document, and then delete that second HTML document.

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE**

The structure of an HTML document should be like this:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

There should only ever be one `<html>` tag opened and closed, one `<head>` tag opened and close, and one `<body>` tag opened and closed.

If you look at your page source you've got a second `<head>` and `<body>` which are causing the problem. The markup is invalid but browsers are clever enough to guess at what you were trying to do which is why it looks ok, but doesn't function quite right.

To fix it, do the following:

Remove line 127 (`<head>`)
Remove line 128 (`<title>Home Page Slide Show</title>`)
Remove lines 129 and 130 (you're already including jQuery further up in your document so you don't need to add it again)
Remove line 148 (`</head>`)
Remove line 149 (`<body>`)
Remove line 151 (`</body>`)

That should do the trick.

Once you've done that run your page through the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix any other validation problems.

I've never had these sort of problems with jQuery Cycle (though someone else has reported a similar thing happening [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-causing-page-jump)) so I can only guess that the problem is with your markup; fix that and you should be golden.

Comment: Hi, firstly I'd like to thank you for answering my question, secondly I have tried to do what you said. would you mind taking a look again for me as the problem is still there. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, yeah the problem's still there. Don't think I can fit it all in to a comment so I'll update the answer above

Answer (score 0):

I see you are still having that problem. Well, I also had same issue in my site. Doing following edits resolved it :

1. instead of display: inline use inline-block. Firefox doesn't like fading of inline elements.(Sorry, don't know exact reason.)
2. Specify width and height in css of the images. Fix them for all images. Wrap them in another div, if possible and fix dimensions of that div. Setting overflow to hidden for it.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the way i fixed it was to make sure that the width and height of all the slideshow images is the same as the width and height of the div that is wrapped around them.